# Can not connect from AWS Lambda to RDS Postgres but can establish socket connection

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

RDS without access to the internet, the same VPC as Lambda. I can connect to RDS from EC2 in the same VPC. I tried to establish a socket connection from Lambda to RDS **successfully**:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print(s.connect(('xxx.cmebgbnbfkax.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 5432)))
```

In logs I see `None` so connection was successful, but I get timeout on connection through psycopg2:

```
psycopg2.connect(
    host='xxx.cmebgbnbfkax.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    dbname=<my db name>,
    user=<my usernamr>,
    password=<my password>)
```

I set maximum timeout on Lambda - 60 seconds. Security group allow access to the port 5432. As I understand if I can establish socket connection to the database - it is mean that all preferences about networking is ok? So where can be a problem?

Comment: How does `None` mean the connection was successful?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot because on incorrect connection will through `ConnectionRefusedError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: I migrated to the DynamoDB - now I do not need compiled `psycopg2` in deployment archive with statically linked libraries.